# Play videos in a directory

Tags: html, video, directory, autoplay

Super green on some of this stuff so I apologize in advance.

I want host video files on my website and have them play in the browser. Currently, when going to the hosted file it just downloads the .mp4. Is there a way to set up a folder of videos to play the video in the browser automatically instead of downloading? I'm trying to avoid having to maintain html and embedding videos. I'd rather just send a url to the specific video and the end user only play that video in the browser.

I have the files hosted on Domain.com. Ideally, I would send a subscriber a link like "www.website.com/videofolder/video_name.mp4" and that video would just play in the browser. Is there a way to do this without making separate html files for each video?

Comment: Please edit your question and elaborate how you're serving files, see answer below

Comment: Make sure the Content-Type: header is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to send an html wrap with the link, this:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="url/to/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Otherwise you'll just be sending a file stream, hence the download you're seeing.

I will also recommend you to explain:

- How you're providing the file to the browser (Hosting),
- Are you using NodeJS, Flask, Django, NGINX, AWS S3, etc.

**So other contributors have more idea of how to help you out.**